# What is __AS3__.vec.Vector

Tags: flash

Is there a defined value to "underscoreunderscoreAS3underscoreunderscore" in the Flash compiler? The IDE is saying that underscoreunderscoreAS3underscoreunderscore.vec.Vector cannot be imported. Is there documentation about doing these type of imports?

Vector is a FP10 class

Comment: It appears this information this information was gleaned from describeType. Where is __AS3__ package documented though?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a bug in Flash Builder apparently

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to import the vector class. it's a top level class. check for a typo:
here is a tutorial to create a vector instance.
[Creating a Vector instance](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7ee5.html#WSB1F41227-C612-4f33-A00E-CE84C1913E1C)

Comment: This is in as3isolib in some classes and vec.Vector is in some Google results but without an explanation as to why it is imported like this.

Answer (score -1):

It is not a bug just check the target of the flash player version and choose latest version.